# Redis Muti/Exec vs Pipelining performance

Tags: redis, jedis

I understand that functionally Multi/Exec and Pipelining are designed to serve different purpose and features.

However, considering only performance for block writes, which would perform better. My understanding is that the Multi/Exec would create a single request, and Pipe lining will create individual requests, but will avoid RTT.

Answer (score 0):

Multi/Exec is slower.

1. Multi/Exec also create individual requests which stored at server side that would be executed one by one when server receiving 'EXEC', and two more requests Multi & Exec.
2. Every request executed in transaction would check if the watched keys changed, which pipelining would never do.